# Aws Lambda slow down after few request

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, google-cloud-functions

I use Amazon Lambda with node12. I run htmlparser2 in my code. When I deploy application, htmlparser2's execution time is around 160ms. But after a while function execution time increases to 5000ms. Do you have any idea? In addition same situation in Google Cloud Functions.

index.js

```
const crawl = require('./crawl.js');

exports.helloWorld = async (req, res) => {
  const url = req.query.url;
  const result = await crawl(url);
  
  res.status(200).type('application/json').send(result);
};
```

crawl.js

```
const bookRecipe = require('./recipes/book');
const quotesRecipe = require('./recipes/quotes');

module.exports =  async (url) => {
  console.log('url', url);
  console.time('books');
  const result = await bookRecipe(url);
  console.timeEnd('books');

  console.time('quotes');
  const quotes = await quotesRecipe(result.quotesLink);
  console.timeEnd('quotes');

  result.quotes = quotes;

  return result;
}
```

recipes/book.js

```
module.exports =  async (url) => {
      const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * agents.length);  
      const agent = agents[random];
    
      console.time("books::fetch")
      const result = await fetch(url, {
        headers: agent
      });
      console.timeEnd("books::fetch");
      
      const text = await result.text();
      console.time('books::parser');
      const dom = htmlparser2.parseDocument(text);
      console.log('books::length', text.length);
      console.timeEnd('books::parser');
    
      console.time('books::cheerio');
      const $ = cheerio.load(dom);
      console.timeEnd('books::cheerio');
      ...
    }
```

Everything is almost same in logs. But htmlparser2's execution is too long in second logs.

Logs:

Normal:

```
    2021-01-26T05:43:28.976+03:00   2021-01-26T02:43:28.976Z 5e3c40c1-36ec-4e94-9230-cbd9d524f984 INFO books::fetch: 134.696ms
    2021-01-26T05:43:29.317+03:00   2021-01-26T02:43:29.317Z 5e3c40c1-36ec-4e94-9230-cbd9d524f984 INFO books::length 520143
    2021-01-26T05:43:29.317+03:00   2021-01-26T02:43:29.317Z 5e3c40c1-36ec-4e94-9230-cbd9d524f984 INFO books::parser: 297.435ms
    2021-01-26T05:43:29.317+03:00   2021-01-26T02:43:29.317Z 5e3c40c1-36ec-4e94-9230-cbd9d524f984 INFO books::cheerio: 0.097ms
    2021-01-26T05:43:29.360+03:00   2021-01-26T02:43:29.360Z 5e3c40c1-36ec-4e94-9230-cbd9d524f984 INFO books: 518.615ms
    2021-01-26T05:43:30.152+03:00   2021-01-26T02:43:30.152Z 5e3c40c1-36ec-4e94-9230-cbd9d524f984 INFO quotes::fetch: 792.172ms
    2021-01-26T05:43:30.218+03:00   2021-01-26T02:43:30.217Z 5e3c40c1-36ec-4e94-9230-cbd9d524f984 INFO quotes::length 312774
    2021-01-26T05:43:30.218+03:00   2021-01-26T02:43:30.217Z 5e3c40c1-36ec-4e94-9230-cbd9d524f984 INFO quotes::parser: 59.300ms
    2021-01-26T05:43:30.218+03:00   2021-01-26T02:43:30.218Z 5e3c40c1-36ec-4e94-9230-cbd9d524f984 INFO quotes::cheerio: 0.081ms
    2021-01-26T05:43:30.520+03:00
2021-01-26T02:43:30.520Z    5e3c40c1-36ec-4e94-9230-cbd9d524f984    INFO    quotes: 1159.586ms
    2021-01-26T02:43:30.520Z 5e3c40c1-36ec-4e94-9230-cbd9d524f984 INFO quotes: 1159.586ms
```

Abnormal:

```
2021-01-26T05:44:48.379+03:00   2021-01-26T02:44:48.379Z 7770ae19-a466-4149-83d2-0d99b9c35a7f INFO books::fetch: 181.431ms
    2021-01-26T05:45:01.737+03:00   2021-01-26T02:45:01.720Z 7770ae19-a466-4149-83d2-0d99b9c35a7f INFO books::length 518608
    2021-01-26T05:45:01.737+03:00   2021-01-26T02:45:01.737Z 7770ae19-a466-4149-83d2-0d99b9c35a7f INFO books::parser: 13316.728ms
    2021-01-26T05:45:01.737+03:00   2021-01-26T02:45:01.737Z 7770ae19-a466-4149-83d2-0d99b9c35a7f INFO books::cheerio: 0.159ms
    2021-01-26T05:45:01.897+03:00   2021-01-26T02:45:01.897Z 7770ae19-a466-4149-83d2-0d99b9c35a7f INFO books: 13699.625ms
    2021-01-26T05:45:02.668+03:00   2021-01-26T02:45:02.667Z 7770ae19-a466-4149-83d2-0d99b9c35a7f INFO quotes::fetch: 770.189ms
    2021-01-26T05:45:09.798+03:00   2021-01-26T02:45:09.797Z 7770ae19-a466-4149-83d2-0d99b9c35a7f INFO quotes::length 313700
    2021-01-26T05:45:09.798+03:00   2021-01-26T02:45:09.798Z 7770ae19-a466-4149-83d2-0d99b9c35a7f INFO quotes::parser: 7117.983ms
    2021-01-26T05:45:09.798+03:00   2021-01-26T02:45:09.798Z 7770ae19-a466-4149-83d2-0d99b9c35a7f INFO quotes::cheerio: 0.123ms
    2021-01-26T05:45:09.861+03:00   2021-01-26T02:45:09.861Z 7770ae19-a466-4149-83d2-0d99b9c35a7f INFO quotes: 7963.365ms
```

Comment: What does "after a while" mean? What documents are you parsing? Have you tested this locally? This question is missing too much information

Comment: Since you are making web requests this might not have to do anything with your code. Networks are not always 100% the same. Maybe the page you are trying to scrape is intentionally throttling you.

Comment: The slown down isn't deterministic. It seems random. But if I deploy again, it's speed became normal.

It isn't related to network. Because network speed time is almost same.